# Get count of multiple values in a dataset table

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I have a dataset table with a column of ParentID and would like to get the count of multiple values in this column into a new table with two fields eg ParentID 5978 and Count of ParentID 4.

Snippet of my table column

```
ParentID
5978
5978
5978
5978
5979
5979
5979
5979
5979
5979
5979
5979
5980
5980
5980
5980
5981
5981
5981
```

Snippet of code:

```
TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
            TreeNodeDataSet parentNodes = tree.SelectNodes(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, "/Shop%", LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture.CultureCode, false, "My.ProductCategory", "OriginalID = " + cId, "NodeID", -1, false, 1);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataSet dx = new DataSet();
            DataSet da = new DataSet();
            ds = parentNodes.Items.FirstItem.Children;
            dx = parentNodes.Items.FirstItem.AllChildren;
            da.Merge(dx.Tables[0].Select("NodeLevel = 4"));
```

The table I want to query is in dataset da

Comment: Snippet of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.  Use GroupBy()

```
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("ParentID", typeof(int));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5978});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5978});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5978});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5978});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5979});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5979});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5979});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5979});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5979});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5979});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5979});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5979});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5980});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5980});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5980});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5980});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5981});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5981});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5981});

            var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("ParentID"))
                .Select(x => new { ParentID = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
                .ToList();
​
```